# How can I display markers using coordinates from a database using php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps-api-3, phpmyadmin

I am building extracting data from a php script using the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("informationquery.php",{lat:lt,lng:lng},function(data){
        displayParkings(data);
    });
});
```

how can I use the result from the code above to display markers on a map?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)...

This is their example *Hello World* map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

There's pretty much all you need in those docs to manipulate maps any way you want

Comment: This is probably more tailored to what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341803/display-markers-on-google-map-using-json